# Load big amount of data from database to pagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

From start I want to apologize for dummy question. I'm new in MVC.

When I'm trying to load all records from database I have wait operation timed out on my Index page.

I'm using PagedList with search fields and clear selection functionality.

My domain model looks like this

```
public class BulbBatch
{
    public int BulbBatchID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Delivery Delivery { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int BulbsAmount { get; set; }
    public int? BoxesAmount { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? CoolingDate { get; set; }
    public int? BatchLocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string BulbBatchBarCode { get; set; }
    public byte[] BulbBatchBarCodeImage { get; set; }
    public string BulbBatchImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

my ViewModel for Index page is next

```
public class BulbBatchViewModel
{
    public int BulbBatchID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Bulb Type Name")]
    public string BulbTypeName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Bulbs Amount")]
    public int BulbsAmount { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Location Name")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

Because i need to use PagedList I created extra viewmodel to be able to implement it.
        using PagedList;

```
public class BulbBatchListViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// fields for searching
    /// </summary>
    public string BulbName { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// using IPageList instead of IEnumerable to create pagination on the view
    /// </summary>
    public IPagedList<BulbBatchViewModel> SearchResult { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
    public string ClearButton { get; set; }
}
```

And finally I have an Action Result Index method inside my controller to retrieve data from database and initialize my BulbBatchesListViewModel.
I also tried to Implement Eager Loading with multiple Include statements to decrease amount of request to the database

```
public ActionResult Index(BulbBatchListViewModel model)
{
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        // creating list with My viewModel for one item of BulbBatc because I need to replace indexes and add extra data from related tables
        List<BulbBatchViewModel> batchesListVM = new List<BulbBatchViewModel>();
        IQueryable<BulbBatch> results;
        string barcode = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode) || model.Page.HasValue)
            barcode = '*' + model.BarCode + '*';
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchButton) || model.Page.HasValue)
        {
            //get all records from database based upon filters                
            results = db.BulbBatches.Include(d => d.Delivery).Include(t => t.Delivery.BulbType).Where(b =>
                                                                    (b.BulbBatchBarCode.Equals(model.BarCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode)) &&
                                                                    (b.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName.ToLower().Equals(model.BulbName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((model.BulbName))) &&
                                                                    (b.Location.LocationName.ToLower().Equals(model.LocationName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LocationName))
                                                                  );
            //initializing of view for each item in result 
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                var batchVM = new BulbBatchViewModel
                {
                    BulbsAmount = item.BulbsAmount,
                    BulbTypeName = item.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName,
                    LocationName = item.Location.LocationName,
                };
                batchesListVM.Add(batchVM);
            }
            var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
            model.SearchResult = batchesListVM.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);
        }
        else
        {
            //get all records from database without filtering filters
            results = db.BulbBatches.Include(d => d.Delivery).Include(t => t.Delivery.BulbType);
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                var batchVM = new BulbBatchViewModel
                {
                    BulbsAmount = item.BulbsAmount,
                    BulbTypeName = item.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName,
                    LocationName = item.Location.LocationName,
                };
                batchesListVM.Add(batchVM);
            }
            var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
            model.SearchResult = batchesListVM.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ClearButton))
        {
            model.BarCode = "";
            model.BulbName = "";
            model.LocationName = "";
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

and when I'm going to the index page first time ( without any kind of filtering/searching) I have an error "The wait operation timed out"

```
results = db.BulbBatches.Include(d => d.Delivery).Include(t => t.Delivery.BulbType);
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    var batchVM = new BulbBatchViewModel
```

...

this is a part of my else statement

When I was trying to load 10 rows from database it works perfectly, but when I put 1000 it stops.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You have only lightweight properties and models. Maybe is your database connection just slow?

Comment: @Marius, nope. Actually as I understood problem was caused by the field         public byte[] BulbBatchBarCodeImage { get; set; } inside My model. So What I did, I changed a selection code a bit and I'm not loading BarCodeImage field anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.
As I understood problem was caused by the field

```
public byte[] BulbBatchBarCodeImage { get; set; }
```

inside My model. So What I did, I changed a selection code a bit and I'm not loading BarCodeImage field anymore.
besides I rebuild Action a bit

```
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<BulbBatchViewModel> results = new List<BulbBatchViewModel>();
        string barcode = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode))
            barcode = '*' + model.BarCode + '*';
        results = db.BulbBatches.Include(d => d.Delivery).Include(t => t.Delivery.BulbType).Include(l => l.Location)
                                .Where(b =>
                                    (b.BulbBatchBarCode.Equals(model.BarCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode)) &&
                                    (b.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName.ToLower().Equals(model.BulbName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((model.BulbName))) &&
                                    (b.Location.LocationName.ToLower().Equals(model.LocationName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LocationName))
                                )
                                .Select(x => new BulbBatchViewModel
                                {
                                    BulbBatchID = x.BulbBatchID,
                                    BulbsAmount = x.BulbsAmount,
                                    BulbTypeName = x.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName,
                                    LocationName = x.Location.LocationName
                                })
                                .ToList();
        model.SearchResult = results.OrderBy(r => r.BulbBatchID).Skip((model.Page - 1) * model.PageSize).Take(model.PageSize).ToList();
        model.TotalRecords = db.BulbBatches.Count(b =>
                                    (b.BulbBatchBarCode.Equals(model.BarCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode)) &&
                                    (b.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName.ToLower().Equals(model.BulbName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((model.BulbName))) &&
                                    (b.Location.LocationName.ToLower().Equals(model.LocationName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LocationName))
                                );
        return View(model);
```

And inside my BulbBatchListViewModel I do not use anymore PagedList but simple List. And with the help of .Take() and .Skip methods I'm navigating through the table.

so for someone who will have the same difficulties.
Updated ViewModel

```
    public class BulbBatchListViewModel
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    ///<summary>
    /// order field
    /// </summary>
    public string Sort { get; set; }
    public string SortDir { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// fields for searching
    /// </summary>
    public string BulbName { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// we are using IPageList instead of IEnumerable to create pagination on the view
    /// </summary>
    //public IPagedList<BulbBatchViewModel> SearchResult { get; set; }
    public List<BulbBatchViewModel> SearchResult { get; set; }
    public string SearchButton { get; set; }
    public string ClearButton { get; set; }

    public BulbBatchListViewModel()
    {
        Page = 1;
        PageSize = 5;
        Sort = "BulbBatchID";
        SortDir = "ASC";
    }
}
```

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Index(BulbBatchListViewModel model)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<BulbBatchViewModel> results = new List<BulbBatchViewModel>();
        string barcode = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode))
            barcode = '*' + model.BarCode + '*';
        results = db.BulbBatches.Include(d => d.Delivery).Include(t => t.Delivery.BulbType).Include(l => l.Location)
                                .Where(b =>
                                    (b.BulbBatchBarCode.Equals(model.BarCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode)) &&
                                    (b.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName.ToLower().Equals(model.BulbName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((model.BulbName))) &&
                                    (b.Location.LocationName.ToLower().Equals(model.LocationName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LocationName))
                                )
                                .Select(x => new BulbBatchViewModel
                                {
                                    BulbBatchID = x.BulbBatchID,
                                    BulbsAmount = x.BulbsAmount,
                                    BulbTypeName = x.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName,
                                    LocationName = x.Location.LocationName
                                })
                                .ToList();
        model.SearchResult = results.OrderBy(r => r.BulbBatchID).Skip((model.Page - 1) * model.PageSize).Take(model.PageSize).ToList();
        model.TotalRecords = db.BulbBatches.Count(b =>
                                    (b.BulbBatchBarCode.Equals(model.BarCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.BarCode)) &&
                                    (b.Delivery.BulbType.BulbName.ToLower().Equals(model.BulbName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((model.BulbName))) &&
                                    (b.Location.LocationName.ToLower().Equals(model.LocationName.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LocationName))
                                );
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks to all of you.